# Deleted /var/cache

Tags: apt, crash, cache

My computer was slowing down, and I saw that deleting /var/log and /var/cache could help, so I did it... I didn't know /var/cache was so important, I tought it would just rebuild itself and deleting old cache would be useful.
Now, apt doesn't work at all. I had some errors messages like "Can't find file /var/cache/xxxx" so I created them all with mkdir. It still didn't work, so I get the clean /var/cache folder on my ubuntu live-cd and copied it, now whenever I use apt-get it only crashes the terminal windows.

I would be extremely thankfull if someone could help me!

Thanks

Comment: `and I saw that deleting /var/log and /var/cache could help` Unrelated question, but where do people find advice like this? I ask in a constructive way - we could try and get them to improve their advice.

Comment: I am using ubuntu since 4/5 years now, and it seems like it's slowing down, so I typed "linux slowing down" and I saw on a forum that you could delete /var/cache and /var/log and actually it made sense for me, because I thought that cache and logs were not important... I know it was stupid to do it without searching more about it on google

Comment: For future reference, deleting files on disk almost never speeds up anything but fairly often breaks something.

Comment: Thanks I think I understood it! But it's not like I microwaved my phone to charge it, it seemed plausible...

Comment: Haha - http://www.firstpost.com/living/trolled-iphone-6-users-try-charge-device-microwave-falling-hoax-1724329.html thanks for the chuckle

Comment: @thomasrutter asks "*where do people find advice like this?*" — About `/var/cache`, [file-hierarchy(7) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/file-hierarchy.7.html) says "*System components may place non-essential data in this directory. Flushing this directory should have no effect on operation of programs, except for increased runtimes necessary to rebuild these caches.*". ¶ I was considering linking it to `/tmp/var_cache`, which is in RAM. Would that be a stupid idea?

Comment: It would appear that not all packages, including some popular packages, fully comply with the intentions of the FHS here, so flat out wiping /var/cache is risky, but if doing so I would ensure that 1) no software using it is running, so do it prior to boot or from a live usb/pxe, and 2) maybe wiping files but leaving the directories there is better.  But it is something I'd be hesitant to do.  In most cases of var/cache occupying too much space on Debian systems, it's APT's package archive and this can be cleared using apt's own commands.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
mkdir /var/cache/apt
mkdir /var/cache/apt/archives
mkdir /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
touch /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin
touch /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
mkdir /var/cache/software-center
mkdir /var/cache/software-center/xapian
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I did what you say, but it still craches when I do apt-get update. Do you know how to see why a terminal crashed? It would help to know what is the error

Comment: dir owner/group also matters, but i don't know yet what it should be.